# PHPMailer with addReplyTo sends OK but the reply sends to SPAM

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, contact-form, spam

My email is received in the inbox in the gmail account.  That part works flawlessly.

The issue is that the reply from the admin gmail account to the sender's email address that is in the addReplyTo fn always goes to that sender's spam folder even in gmail, yahoo, etc.

This is not ideal.  Because customers will email and expect replies to go to their inbox and not their spam folder.

**Currently:**
contact form -> admin gmail inbox - replies to sender gmail -> goes to sender gmail spam

**Ideally:**
contact form -> admin gmail inbox - replies to sender gmail -> goes to sender gmail inbox

This may be out of my control but is there anything else I can do? Headers? I already have DKIM set up.

```
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host     = 'smtp.myhosting.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'admin@website.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;


$receiver_email = 'admin_gmail_account@gmail.com';
$receiver_name = 'Customer Service';

$sender_email = $_POST["email"]
$sender_name = $_POST["name"]

$mail->setFrom('admin@website.com');
$mail->addAddress($receiver_email, $receiver_name);
$mail->addReplyTo($sender_email, $sender_name);

// DKIM signing here
```

Comment: Before you attack this with code, are your SPF, DKIM and DMARC records correct? If not, start there.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - They all appear correct.  I see "pass" when looking at the original text and headers inside gmail.

Comment: If the admin is not even responding _via_ your system in the first place, but simply does that by logging into their Gmail web UI, or by using their local email client - then I don't think there is too much you can do, from your end. The content of the email you are sending might play a part - especially if the admin were to, say, "quote" a really marketing-y looking original email when responding. Send one of those replies to https://www.mail-tester.com, and see what that has to say.

Comment: The message you’re concerned about isn’t sent by PHPMailer but whatever you’re replying with, so I think you’re looking in the wrong place. If you view source in gmail, it will usually tell you why a message has ended up in spam in the headers.

Comment: But apart from what the email actually contains, I think the main issue might simply be, that your admin is basically a "rando" here in this situation, who is all of a sudden initiating contact with me, the customer. _I_ have never mailed your admin from my actual account address before (that's the situation, right?), they are not in my contacts ... So getting a "reply" now to a mail I never actually personally sent in the first place, might be a problem.

Comment: To give more context.  The contact form is pretty straight - name, email, phone.  And I have tested with a reply from a secondary gmail account with a simple "thank you".  So I feel like I am missing something small with PHPMailer...

Comment: @CBroe - I think your second comment is the actual answer here.  The more I dig the more everything looks as it should.  But the "getting a "reply" now to a mail I never actually personally sent in the first place, might be a problem" seems to be the actual reason

Comment: It could still be a combination of multiple factors though. I mean, I should be able to initiate contact with a new conversation partner via the medium "email", without that going into the spam folder _per se_ in every single instance, right? I'd recommend you do the https://www.mail-tester.com/ check, by sending one of those replies there. Could be stuff like quoted HTML content(?) of the original email  or something else considered "a bit spammy" is what tips it over the edge, when it occurs in combination with "I don't know that sender."

Comment: Also, how many times did you have this happen already by now? If a "considerable" amount (whatever that actually might be, LOL) of mails from this sender address has already been classified as spam, and not manually rectified by enough of the recipients, that address might be "burned" by now ... So you might have more luck with a "fresh" one.

Comment: @CBroe - Actually it has not happened alot.  Up until yesterday the was no addReplyTo and they were "replying" by clicking the email in the message body.  Got an 8.7 with the biggest hit being "FREEMAIL_REPLY From and body contain different freemails"